# Inserting the values retrieved from the statement into a newly created dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert new dataframe searched results below

```
## results
df.workclass.value_counts()


 Private             22696
 Self-emp-not-inc     2541
 Local-gov            2093
 State-gov            1298
 Self-emp-inc         1116
 Federal-gov           960
 Without-pay            14
 Never-worked            7


## new dataframe 
dic = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'col_name','origin_value','trans_value'})
```

I want to insert all the searched values into a new dataframe directly like SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, You need to use `apply()`.

```
dic = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col_name','origin_value','trans_value'])

# Iterate through the values in the of 'workclass' 
for value in df.workclass.value_counts().index:
    # Add a new row to the new dataframe with the column name, original value, and transformed value
    dic = dic.append({'col_name': 'workclass', 'origin_value': value, 'trans_value': value}, ignore_index=True)
```